# Serverless best way of using generated lambda endpoint into static javascript code

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a `serverless` project which deploys a lambda function and also a static web page. 
The js code on the static web page has the hard-coded endpoint of the lambda function.

Whats the proper way to deploy the lambda and then use the generated endpoint in the 
static js code before deploy.

Is there any templating method so

Thanks!

Comment: https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-to-export-api-url-in-serverless-yml/4996

Answer (score 0):

This is how i defined the IoT Endpoint on `aws-sdk-go-v2`

```
  config, _ := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
  config.EndpointResolver = aws.ResolveWithEndpointURL("https://xxxxxx")
  
  dataplaneClient := iotdataplane.New(config)
```

On the original `aws-sdk-go` you set it on the `aws.Config` struct directly:

```
svc := iotdataplane.New(session.New(), &aws.Config {Endpoint: aws.String("http://xxxx")})
```

I found the solution on a test case on https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2